# Meaning of "snake in the grass"

Tags: meaning, idioms

I have tried to find this but failed, so I want to ask here. What is the meaning of *snake in the grass*?

Comment: This can be solved via a simple dictionary lookup: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+snake+in+the+grass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone who pretends to be your friend while secretly doing things to harm you.

This can also be likened to a "double agent"

Answer (score 2):

I would understand it more broadly, as a hidden danger, something that can harm you suddenly, unexpectedly. That can also be a false friend, yes. But double agent is not quite the same.